# Let $a_n$ be the number of options to get the sum $n$ by using odd-numbers from the interval $[3,15]$?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a_n$ be the number of options to get the sum $n$ by using odd-numbers from the interval $[3,15]$ {They don't have to be different numbers}

what is the generating function of $(a_n)_n^{\infty}$?

The answer needs to be as a closed function not as infinite sums... Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the order of the summands is irrelevant, the generating function is

$$
\prod_{k=1}^7\left(1+x^{2k+1}+\left(x^{2k+1}\right)^2+\dotso\right)=\prod_{k=1}^7\frac1{1-x^{2k+1}}\;.
$$

If the order is relevant, let $z=x^3+x^5+x^7+x^9+x^{11}+x^{13}+x^{15}=x^3(1-x^{14})/(1-x^2)$. Then the generating function is

$$
1+z+z^2+\dotso=\frac1{1-z}=\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^2-x^3+x^{17}}\;.
$$

Comment: Sorry for being lame, but $x^3(1−x^{14})/(1−x^2)$ is an identity for the former expression?

Comment: @TheAlchemist: Yes; this is the summation of a finite geometric sum: $1+x+x^2+\dotso x^k=(1-x^{k+1})/(1-x)$. By the way, you need to enclose exponents consisting of more than one character in braces (`{}`) to group them into an exponent.

Comment: Still can't see how you got it using that formula.

Comment: Never mind, got it now :-)